# How do I open multiple bootstrap modals simultaneously in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a table with a list of records on the main landing page.

We can click records from the table to open a bootstrap modal for detail view.

I want to access the main landing page table to open another bootstrap modal, I mean opening and keeping two of them simultaneously.

Comment: Something wrong with `window.open()`?

Comment: @daniel  I am using bootstrap modal window. not the new browser window popup.

Comment: You might want to mention that fact in the question, then.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: "popup window" does not mean "modal". They are different things.   Edited for you.

Comment: i have something similar. just open the second modal from within the other. and if you attach a mouse handle or something else, you can drag your modal around. so that you see the other content.

Comment: I think you don't want a modal window. You want another window that acts like a popup panel. Modal window requires for you to complete interaction before you can do anything back on the parent window. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Comment: we should allow them to click main landing page table records,based on the records user clicked modal window shows detail information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achived this using angular-kendo window , Now able to open multiple popup.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BE6ADurYGqikkcNKQVl7?p=preview

```
var windowInstance = $kWindow.open({
                   options:{
                     modal: false,
                     title: "Window title",
                     height: 150,
                     width: 400,
                     visible: false
                   },
                    templateUrl: 'modal1.html',
                    controller: 'modalController',
                    resolve: {
                        parameter1: function () {
                            return "Test...";
                        }
                    }
                });
                windowInstance.result.then(function (result) {
                    // Here you can get result from the window
                });
```

Comment: your solution doesn't seem to work in the way you mentioned, at least in the plunker example.